# How do I add a second subscriber to SQL 2005 Transactional Replication publication

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I have setup SQL 2005 Transactional Replication, with one master database acting as the publisher, and one subscriber.  It's running fine.  Now, I want to add a second subscriber to this publication.  I created the subscription on the second server, and created the snapshot ok, but when it starts to syncronize I get the error

"Cannot drop the table 'xxxxx' because it is being used for replication."

How do I add a second subscriber to an existing publication that already has one subscriber?   I don't want to stop the first subscription that already exists and is working fine if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Before syncronizing I had restored a backup of the database to the new subscriber that was enabled for replication.  So most of the tables had the "Table is replicated" property set to True.  I ran sp_removedbreplication on the database (on the new subscriber) and it set that property to False for all the tables which allowed the syncronization to work without errors.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your target table for the second subscription is being replicated (i.e., it's already a publication).  That's what the error indicates.  Does the table already exist on the subscribing database?